# Python nested for loop issues

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, nested

I am trying to use a nested for loop to simply add two sets of numbers together respectively.

```
x=[1,2,3,4]
f=[0,1,2,3]

for i in x:
    for j in f:
        ans = i+j
        ans2 = j
print(ans,ans2)
```

My output is

```
6 5
7 5
8 5
9 5
```

However, I want it to be

```
 1 0
 3 1
 5 2
 7 3
```

I'm not quite sure where i'm going wrong and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your output cannot be produced by your code. A nested loop such as yours would run 16 iterations, and an unindented print would only print two values. Since you only want 4 iterations, a nested loop is not what you need; look at the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the index into `x` to get the appropriate value of `f` to use as `j`. You can do this by iterating over the [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)d `x`:

```py
x=[1,2,3,4]
f=[0,1,2,3]

for idx, i in enumerate(x):
    j = f[idx]
    ans = i+j
    ans2 = j
    print(ans,ans2)
```

Alternatively you could use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and iterate both values at once:

```py
for i, j in zip(x, f):
    ans = i+j
    ans2 = j
    print(ans,ans2)
```

In both cases the output is:

```
1 0
3 1
5 2
7 3
```